# Pathfinding algorithm to find if each piece is connected to a specific object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I'm making a game where the player has to rotate pipes to connect them to a source of water, but i'm getting **stack overflow** at certain point and i don't know where and why. Is there a pathfinding algorithm suitet for this situation?

The first level so far looks like this:

[image: Level One]

The "grid" is 9x9. The blue cross is the source of water and the other pipes have to check if they have a valid path to the source.

Each pipe object looks like this:

[image: Pipe Example]

It consists is a parent `game object` to hold everything, the watered pipe object, a `collider` to detect the mouse clicks and 3 `circle colliders` to detect collision with the other pipes. This setup with all of those colliders is what i managed to make work. The empty pipe and the filled pipe both have a `polygon collider` to prevent colliding with the `circe colliders` in weird angles. The 3 `circle collider` objects are needed because of the different entrances of the pipe.

Now about the code:

I tried to create a pathfinding algorithm by myself to check if each tile have a valid path to the water source. I have no idea why it`s causing stack overflow.

Here is the pathfinding method:

```
    public bool FindSourceOfWater() {
        foreach (var item in collidedList) {
            if (!checkedObjectsList.Contains(item)) {
                Pipe targetObjectScript = item.GetComponent<Pipe>();
                checkedObjectsList.Add(item);
                if (item.CompareTag("Pipes_WaterSource")) {
                    checkedObjectsList.Clear();
                    return true;
                } else {
                    targetObjectScript.checkedObjectsList.Add(gameObject);
                    if (targetObjectScript.FindSourceOfWater()) {
                        checkedObjectsList.Clear();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        checkedObjectsList.Clear();
        return false;
    }
```

What the code does:

- Every currently collided item is added to a list. The foreach run through that list.
- If the target object isn`t in the list of already checked objects, proceed.
- Get the same script in the target object and add that object to the already checked objects list.
- If the tag from the target object math, clear the checked objects list and return true. This means that the object that called the method is connected to the water source.
- If the tag don't match, add this object to the target's list of already checked objects (to prevent infinite looping).
- Now it calls the targets FindSourceOfWater method.
- If the method called returns true, then this instance also returns true.
- If not, then proceed to the next collided object.

The methods is called during update:

```
    private void Update() {
        if (collidedList.Count != 0) {
            isConnectedToWaterSource = FindSourceOfWater();
        } else {
            isConnectedToWaterSource = false;
        }
        if (isConnectedToWaterSource && !filledPipe.activeSelf) {
            filledPipe.SetActive(true);
        } else if (!isConnectedToWaterSource && filledPipe.activeSelf) {
            filledPipe.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

The StackOverflow error links to this line:

`if (item.CompareTag("Pipes_WaterSource")) {`

It`s intended to return true if it has a valid connection to the water source tile. But i guess it`s calling the method too many times. Maybe because it`s been called in the update? So everyone is checking for a source of water at the same time.

Comment: Is my understanding correct that each item has a own already-checked-items list? That doesn't seem right to me (but I don't think my understanding is correct). I'd also recommend using a non-recursive search routine in case the input can be larger.

Comment: Oh the irony, having an overflow when working with pipes :3

For the actual question though, I see you are calling that function "recursively" (on a different instance, but still). Maybe try to re-write it in an imperative manner first to see more clearly?

Comment: I'd recommend doing this recursive check with the source of the water as your starting point, rather than doing this check for every single pipe, you'd save some processing power.  You could build up a list of pipes connected to the source, and then work off that.  Maybe make a "ConnectedToWaterManager" singleton that would only need to be updated once per cycle, instead of every pipe needing to run this algorithm, you'd update each pipe based off the results of that singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For context, this problem space is know as [Graph Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal) (in case you'd like to further study these sorts of things) and there doesn't seem to be a need here for recursion.  Also, your variable names with "list" in them imply you're using `List<T>` but [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) performs `Contains()` in O(1) time (as opposed to `List<T>` doing in in O(n) time) in addition to **ensuring its contents are unique**; it's better suited for your problem.

To fix your issue, you can just use a `HashSet<T>` along with a [`Stack<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=netframework-4.7.2); one of items you've already checked, and one of items remaining to be checked.  While there are still items remaining to be checked, pop one off and evaluate it.  If it's connected to anything that hasn't already been checked, add it to the checked set and push it onto the stack.

Here's your algorithm, slightly modified:

```
public bool FindSourceOfWater() {
    //Prep collections with this object's connections
    var checkedSet = new HashSet<ItemType>(collidedList);
    var remainingStack = new Stack<ItemType>(collidedList);

    //Are there items left to check?
    while (remainingStack.Count > 0) {
        //Reference the next item and remove it from remaining
        var item = remainingStack.Pop();
        Pipe targetObjectScript = item.GetComponent<Pipe>();

        //If it's the source, we're done
        if (item.CompareTag("Pipes_WaterSource")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            //Otherwise, check for new items to evaluate
            //(You'll have to publicly expose collidedList for this)
            foreach (var newItem in targetObjectScript.collidedList) {
                //HashSet.Add returns true if it's added and false if it's already in there
                if (checkedSet.Add(newItem)) {
                    //If it's new, make sure it's going to be evaluated
                    remainingStack.Push(newItem);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

Note: You could also use a [`Queue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) for a breadth-first search instead of a `Stack<T>` (which makes this a depth-first traversal).

Answer (score 1):

I would make a manager object that handles this for you, as opposed to running this in the update of every pipe object you have, you would only run it once in the manager object and either have the manager update all the pipes, or poll the manager class from inside your pipe's update method.

*disclaimer: This is only an example algorithm, and code improvements could certainly be made.*

```
public class WaterConnectionManager
{
    static IList<Pipe> WaterConnectedPipes = new List<Pipe>();
    static IList<Pipe> AllPipes = new List<Pipe>();

    static void UpdatePipes()
    {
        //get the starting point for this algorithm
        Pipe waterSource = GetWaterSource();

        //recurse for all connected pipes
        UpdateWaterConnectedPipesList(waterSource);

        //Update each pipe with its current status
        foreach(Pipe pipe in AllPipes)
        {
            pipe.IsWaterConnected = WaterConnectedPipes.Contains(pipe);
        }
    }

    static void UpdateWaterConnectedPipesList(Pipe sourcePipe)
    {
        //create a method that returns connected pipes on your Pipe script.
        IEnumerable<Pipe> connectedPipes = sourcePipe.GetConnectedPipes();

        foreach(Pipe connectedPipe in connectedPipes)
        {
            //prevent infinite recursion
            if (WaterConnectedPipes.Contains(connectedPipe))
            {
                continue;
            }

            //store these connected pipes for later recursions/iterations
            WaterConnectedPipes.Add(connectedPipe);

            //recurse into the connected pipe, to find its connected pipes.
            UpdateWaterConnectedPipesList(connectedPipe);
        }
    }

    static Pipe GetWaterSource()
    {
        return AllPipes.First(p => p.IsWaterSource);
    }

}
```